# npm publish failing with 'User not found <package-name>'

Tags: npm, publish

I'm pretty stuck trying to publish a package -- I've tried it both from local file system and github repos url - same issue.

I've created a detailed issue on the github npm repo [here](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/19387), but I'm getting crickets.

Wonder if someone here might scan the issue and help me out?

Thanx.

Comment: You reference in your `"main"` a file that doesn't exist (it's a build product) and which is further git-ignored. Have you seen this pattern used elsewhere? I've never seen a package do that.

Comment: My understanding is the "main" file is what will be 'served' up as the entry point for the package.  In this case, it is something that would exist only after it's built.

However, I'm specifying "prepublishOnly", which I believe builds it before publishing so the file should exist.

'dist' is in gitignore, but not in .npmignore (which is empty -- I want all files to be published, including the 'dist' when it's built.)(and the 'src' directory for reference.)

So, am I not interpreting something correctly in how publish works?

Comment: At any rate, thanks for the suggestion, but I don't think it is the cause of the publisher interpreting the 'package name' as the 'user name'.

Answer (score 1):

Per comment from Ibis Liven (github NPM issue [#19404](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/19404)), I created an account on the NPM website and then the publish worked from the command line as expected.

Seems the `adduser` command is broken.